# Не получается несколько условий в if

Tags: php

```
<?php
$chasov = date('G');

if($chasov >= 21 and $chasov < 9) {$kruglyash4 = "1";}

var_dump($kruglyash4);
?>
```

Выдаёn мне null, но если будет только одно условие, то всё будет работать

Т.е вот так всё работает:

```
<?php
    $chasov = date('G');

    if($chasov < 9) {$kruglyash4 = "1";}

    var_dump($kruglyash4);
    ?>
```

Comment: а как может быть одновременно $chasov >= 21 и < 9? Такое условие никогда не выполнится

Comment: может быть нужно не **и** а **или**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так, если необходимо выполнения хотя бы одного из условий :

```
if ($chasov >= 21 || $chasov < 9) { ... }
```

Comment: Слишком много скобок.

Comment: @Visman, так лучше?)

Comment: Нет, надо проверку выполнения двух условий. Что бы было больше или равно 21, и меньше 9

Comment: @SatontWorldwide, так не бывает. Число не может быть одновременно И больше 21 И меньше 9

Comment: Вот так правильно без лишних скобок.

Comment: @Damon Haswell по своей тупости даже не подумал об этом, спасибо, всё верно

Comment: @Visman, спасибо за поправку.